# MacBook Pro (Early 2015) Catalina bluetooth issues

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, catalina, bluetooth

My MacBook Pro 13" Early 2015 was working without any problems until I've updated it to 10.15.5

Under Bluetooth section in System Report there was "No information found" message.

Tried resetting NVRAM, SMC and reinstalling Catalina from Recovery mode but nothing helped. For OS to start recognizing BT module I had to run the following sequence of commands:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.bluetoothd
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
rm ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.*
```

Then, I had to shut down the Mac, wait one minute and start it in Safe mode (by holding Shift button pressed during boot). After logging in, it appeared in System Report and Settings:

[image: Sysreport]

But it doesn't see any devices and my Mac doesn't appear in the lists of devices on my phone.

[image]

I've also tried shutting down my router which broadcasting 5Ghz network but it has no effect at all.

Does that mean it's a software issue or my bluetooth is broken somehow?

Comment: Your AirPort card (handles Bluetooth) may have died.  It’s being seen by the system, but can see or be seen by other devices.  The transiever Portion of the chip may have died.

Comment: Thank you. Is this Bluetooth transceiver is independent from Wifi transceiver? Because Wifi works perfectly. If bluetooth has died, fixing it means replacing whole card, right?

Comment: Yes...Same component different radio.  Try running [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting).  However, Apple has "crippled" the more recent versions (if this were a 2012 MBP - Diags were pretty good).  Let's see what we get